# How to remove time stamp from date field in InfoPath form?

Tags: infopath, date-time, data, formatting

I have a drop down in an InfoPath form that grabs data from a SharePoint list. One of the fields in the form is a date field and when it gets populated with the date from SharePoint it includes the time stamp.

It looks like this: **2016-01-01T00:00:00**

I have the formatting set on the field as "3/14/2001". How can I remove the "T00:00:00"?

Comment: I added "substring-before" to the function in the rule and extracted just the date!

Comment: Really consider using a library like Moment.js. It will format in desired result :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out without any custom code! I just added this to the function:

**substring-before**(field1, "T")

This extracted all the text before the "T"!

Comment: Really consider using a library like Moment.js. It will format in desired result :)